# Rails app in production: can't load css and js files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I have a Rails 6 app that I'm trying to put in production but the css and js files can't be loaded.

I get the following error in the browser's console:

```
GET mydomain.com/packs/js/application-d0f5393dfb6f4a59c02e.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

GET mydomain.com/packs/css/application-a03bb908.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Note that I don't have any errors in my log/production/log file.

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  # config.require_master_key = true

  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true

  config.public_file_server.headers = {
    "Cache-Control" => "public, max-age=31536000",
  }

  # Compress CSS using a preprocessor.
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js ^[^_]*.css *.css.erb )

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  config.active_storage.service = :local_production

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain.
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = false

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment).
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "bounty_production"

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  # Inserts middleware to perform automatic connection switching.
  # The `database_selector` hash is used to pass options to the DatabaseSelector
  # middleware. The `delay` is used to determine how long to wait after a write
  # to send a subsequent read to the primary.
  #
  # The `database_resolver` class is used by the middleware to determine which
  # database is appropriate to use based on the time delay.
  #
  # The `database_resolver_context` class is used by the middleware to set
  # timestamps for the last write to the primary. The resolver uses the context
  # class timestamps to determine how long to wait before reading from the
  # replica.
  #
  # By default Rails will store a last write timestamp in the session. The
  # DatabaseSelector middleware is designed as such you can define your own
  # strategy for connection switching and pass that into the middleware through
  # these configuration options.
  # config.active_record.database_selector = { delay: 2.seconds }
  # config.active_record.database_resolver = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver
  # config.active_record.database_resolver_context = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver::Session

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :postmark

  config.action_mailer.postmark_settings = { api_token: Rails.application.credentials.postmark_api_token }

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "mydomain.com" }
end
```

**config/webpacker.yml**

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .erb
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

**What I tried**

I searched a lot of similar issues on stackoverflow and usually, the solution was to add

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

or

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

but it didn't change anything for me.

My assets are precompiled as I'm running `rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production` everytime before launching my server.

What is also really strange is that I have some pictures on my website that are loading correctly.

For example, `mydomain.com/assets/main_picture-10fb4732e9edf8992cd02fb1425ef98ab13b0ce139d6df5299a41acf9093f0b3.png` is working correctly. But, `mydomain.com/packs/css/application-a03bb908.css` returns an error telling me that this page doesn't exist.

And when I'm looking into my public folder (on my server):

```
ls public/packs/css
application-a03bb908.css  application-a03bb908.css.br  application-a03bb908.css.gz
```

So the file does exist but somehow my application can't access it.

Any clue on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Can you tell me how did you solved this?